# Migrating from FOSUserBundle to Django

Tags: django, fosuserbundle

I'm in the process of migrate a php site with FOSUserBundle to a Django user model.

The content of `app/config/security.yml`:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
```

Values of password/salt from a user test at the PHP site:

- password: `3EBoIIMrD73n2y+4hMUpCq2lmJ8tHStrBweonQClP+/Jhmaw7ipLbamQJQfB87Acg45sBH3HlgnpKI+QZN7m/Q==`
- salt: `2n4fxtazv1us0csgg8s880ck4skcskg`
- The password used is `amdpower`

I've tried to generate the same hash with this code:

```
raw_password = 'amdpower'
salt = '2n4fxtazv1us0csgg8s880ck4skcskg'

salted = '%s{%s}' % (raw_password, salt)
digest =  hashlib.sha512(salted).digest()
for i in range(5000):
   digest = hashlib.sha512(digest).digest()
print base64.b64encode(digest)
>>> wqgbbFZ/IPvwZktbmYz7inffofmT5HbRNf04BQ+w33Jgman8uVYbjWyiKzfp5EIFX2wqYGOb7hRzi5BdZlzDKw==
```

What's wrong with the hashing code I've tried? How can I generate the same hash?

Update:

The PHP funcs are:

- FOSUserBundle: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/UserManager.php#L180
- Symfony: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder

Solved:

```
raw_password = 'amdpower'
salt = '2n4fxtazv1us0csgg8s880ck4skcskg'

salted = '%s{%s}' % (raw_password, salt)
digest =  hashlib.sha512(salted).digest()
for i in range(4999):
    digest = hashlib.sha512('%s%s' % (digest, salted)).digest()
print base64.b64encode(digest)
>>> 3EBoIIMrD73n2y+4hMUpCq2lmJ8tHStrBweonQClP+/Jhmaw7ipLbamQJQfB87Acg45sBH3HlgnpKI+QZN7m/Q==
```

Comment: Are you certain that this is how the salt is added to the password *in the PHP code?* Have you looked at the specific PHP code to see how/what they are invoking the hash? Do you know for certain that the PHP code & lib are correct? (I ask because PHP code runs the gamut from excellent to WTF.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over here, I've recreated the scenario over how Symfony hashes the password.

http://codepad.org/AhC64q4r

Now it's all about converting it to python, which I know you can do it Juan :)